# Error response from daemon: failed to parse Dockerfile: Syntax error - can't find = in "\"\"". Must be of the form: name=value

Tags: dockerfile

Trying to build a docker image and it keeps returning the error in the title:

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM java:8
ADD build/libs/selfservingportal.jar selfservingportal.jar
ENV SSL_CERT= ""
ENV SSL_KEY=""
ENV DEVSECOPS_PLATFORM_TERRAFORM_API_TOKEN=""
ENV DEVSECOPS_PLATFORM_TERRAFORM_USER=""
ENV DEVSECOPS_PLATFORM_TERRAFORM_BASEURL=""
ENV DEVSECOPS_PLATFORM_CREATED_TERRAFORM_API_TOKEN=""
ENV GCP_CAPTCHA_TOKEN=""
ENV JENKINS_BASE=""
ENV JENKINS_EXTENSION=""
ENV JENKINS_APPLICATIONJOB=""
ENV JENKINS_INFRASTRUCTUREJOB=""
ENV DEVSECOPS_PLATFORM_CREATED_TERRAFORM_USER=""
ENV ACCESS_KEY=""
ENV SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=""
ENV AWS_REGION=""
ENV AWS_ACCESSKEY=""
ENV AWS_SECRETKEY=""
ENV AZURE_CLIENT_ID=""
ENV AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY=""
ENV AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=""
ENV AZURE_TENANT_ID=""
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","selfservingportal.jar"]
```

Not sure what the problem with the syntax is here. Is it because the values are empty? Very confused. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally noticed the stray space after the = in:

```
ENV SSL_CERT= ""
```

Removing this solved the issue.